# How to make the iPhone camera read a QR code and go to my app instead of safari

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, deep-linking

I want to create a QR code that I can take the regular ios camera app hover over it and then have my phone transition to the app I developed.

However, when I make a QR code from my URL Scheme, the QR code reader in the camera automatically takes me to a safari website where there is no website for my scheme (obviously).  How can I fix this so that the camera QR read takes the iPhone user to my app instead of passing the app scheme url into safari?

[image]

Comment: What if you use a universal link instead?

Comment: I tried that as well.  [Examine this url](https://mocki.io/v1/e8e50d4c-a32f-4734-b067-f2a513138766).  I replaced the <TeamID> with my team id found in the [Apple developer member site](https://developer.apple.com/account/#!/membership).  I'm using [this](https://mocki.io/fake-json-api) to provide the JSON.  I'm using this to get the [QR code](https://www.qr-code-generator.com) from the URL.

Comment: I will try [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection) next.